# need some help to vectorize this code for images

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any way to vectorize this code. It is similar to bitwise and? IF "A" is a greyscale image and "B" is a binary image and "C" is matrix of same size of "A" containing zeroes

```
for row in range(A.shape[0]):
    for col in range(A.shape[1]):
        if B[row, col] == 1:
            C[row, col] = ~A[row, col]
        else:
            C[row, col] = A[row, col]
```

Comment: Try with `C[B == 1] = ~A`, `C[B != 1] = A` and see how it goes.

Comment: @zvone i got this error "NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions"

Comment: Ah, OK, I'll write an answer :)

Comment: @zvone using your logic i tried using numpy.putmask(C,B,A) but it's not giving the result i want. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny sorry, I changed it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it using [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
C = np.where(B == 1, ~A, A)
```

Answer (score 1):

If A, B, and C are `numpy` arrays of the same size, you can do operations on the whole array, with approximately the same code you would write for each value.

So, you can do a `B == 1` to get a boolean array of the same size as `B` e.g. `[True, False, True, False]`. A `C[B == 1]` will then be a sub-array of `C` at all indices at which `B` contains `1`.

To sum it all up, you can do this:

```
C[B == 1] = ~A[B == 1]
C[B != 1] = A[B != 1]
```

Alternatively, if you don't even have a `C` to start with:

```
C = A.copy()
C[B == 1] = ~C[B == 1]
```

---

BTW, I would recommend using `a`, `b`, and `c` rather than `A`, `B`, and `C`, because that is how we usually name variables in Python. See [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more info.

Comment: Isn't `A[B == 1]` a typo?  Seems like that should be `A[B != 1]`.